# Why is this string multiplication throwing an error?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
x = 0.8
y = str(x)
x=x*y
print x, y
```

---

Just beginning Python, not looking to fix the code, rather work out how to justify why there is an error. I believe that this attempts to pass a string off as an integer just not sure why you can't do that.

Comment: `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'` - This error message means that you are trying to multiply a sequence type with a float. Technically, a string is a sequence of characters.

Comment: What would you *expect* `0.8 * "0.8"` to evaluate to? A zero, a full stop and two fifths of an 8?

Answer (score 2):

You have this:

```
x = 0.8      # float
y = str(0.8)
```

the last line, will be equivalent to

```
y = "0.8"    # string
```

then, when you do

```
x = x * y    # float * string
```

you get an error, because it's not possible to multiply a string with a float. But **note** that you can do that with integers:

```
x = 3
y = str(6)   # y = "6"
```

this will produce the output `"666"`, because it's multiplying the string `"6"` 3 times.